# SQL join table result of 2 statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress, join

I am trying to get data with SQL from my Wordpress database by a JOIN, but I do not get it working.

**What I need:**

- Posts where the meta_key "gtp_product_dont_show" exists and where the meta_value not is "true".
- And posts where the meta_key "gtp_product_dont_show" does not exists.

**My Problem:**

I now only get the results where posts have a meta_key "gtp_product_dont_show", but there are also posts which don't have this key, and I need these as well.

**This is what I have now:**

```
SELECT 
    ID, post_title
FROM 
    wp_posts p
    JOIN wp_postmeta m ON 
        p.ID = m.post_id AND 
        m.meta_key = 'gtp_product_dont_show' AND 
        m.meta_value != 'true'
WHERE 
    post_type = 'products' AND 
    post_status = 'publish'
```

**Output:**

Comment: please give sample input and outputs

Comment: then remove the meta_key stuff from the query. you're telling the db to return only records that have that value. if you want records that don't, then you can't require it be there. "you must be wearing a green tshirt, but cannot be wearing green - hey! why am I not getting any green?"

Comment: @MarcB I don't think it can be removed. Consider the case where `m.meta_key = 'gtp_product_dont_show' and m.meta_value = 'true'`, I believe OP is trying to exclude that.

Comment: However, I do think this question would be more clear with sample data and expected results, I agree with Onur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `left join`:

```
SELECT ID, post_title
FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN
     wp_postmeta m
     ON p.ID = m.post_id AND 
        m.meta_key = 'gtp_product_dont_show' 
WHERE (m.meta_value is null or m.meta_value <> 'true') and
      post_type = 'products' AND 
      post_status = 'publish';
```

The `left join` looks for an appropriate key in the `wp_postmeta` table.  The `where` clause then says "keep a record when there is no match or the value is not true" -- which I think is the logic you are looking for.

Comment: I got an error on this one which says: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm.meta_value != 'true' WHERE (m.meta_value is null or m.meta_value <> 'true') an' at line 6

Comment: @Robert . . . That line should have been deleted.  THe logic is in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this?

```
SELECT 
    ID, post_title
FROM 
    wp_posts p
WHERE 
    post_type = 'products' AND 
    post_status = 'publish' AND
    not exists (
        select 1 
        from wp_postmeta m
        where 
        p.ID = m.post_id AND 
        m.meta_key = 'gtp_product_dont_show' AND 
        m.meta_value = 'true')
```

This will fetch all the rows from wp_posts, but leave out those where row is found from wp_postmeta where meta_key is gtp_product_dont_show and value is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OR` operator to consider both conditions. Try this:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM myTable
JOIN otherTable ON 
   (m.meta_key = 'gtp_product_dont_show' AND m.meta_value != 'true') OR 
   (m.meta_key != 'gtp_product_dont_show')
...
```

Just a side note, I don't recommend storing booleans as strings like that. You should consider using a `TINYINT()` where boolean fields are stored as 0 for false, or 1 for true.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and the boolean tip. I have tried this earlier, but this doesn't work.

Comment: @Robbert Can you add some sample data and expected results? I'm not really sure what you mean by 'not exists' with the meta_key. If you can build an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) that would be the most helpful.